# How does neomodel in python connects neo4j db without db name?

Tags: python, neo4j, neomodel

I am just starting with neo4j database. I am using neomodel in Python, to connect with neo4j.

For this, I created a new database with name "kat" and gave it a password - "password".

After running the following code, I am able to create a new person called Jim in the database:

```
from neomodel import (config, StructuredNode, StringProperty, IntegerProperty,
    UniqueIdProperty, RelationshipTo, RelationshipFrom)

config.DATABASE_URL = 'bolt://neo4j:password@localhost:7687'

class Country(StructuredNode):
    code = StringProperty(unique_index=True, required=True)
    inhabitant = RelationshipFrom('Person', 'IS_FROM')


class Person(StructuredNode):
    uid = UniqueIdProperty()
    name = StringProperty(unique_index=True)
    age = IntegerProperty(index=True, default=0)
    country = RelationshipTo(Country, 'IS_FROM')


jim = Person(name='Jim', age=3).save()
jim.age = 4
jim.save() # validation happens here
# jim.delete()
# jim.refresh() # reload properties from neo
print(jim.id) # neo4j internal id
```

What I don't understand is, I have not mentioned the name of the database anywhere in the code, but still I can see this node being created in the db. Can anyone explain? I used this as a setup guide - https://neomodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Comment: No need to specify the database, there is only one database active at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **only one database active in neo4j** and It's defined in `conf/neo4j.conf` file.

You can create more databases and but cannot have multiple databases active at the same time.

If you want, you can change the active database in `conf/neo4j.conf` file.

Change below line to point to new database.

```
dbms.active_database=graph.db
```

Comment: This statement is not completely true as of Neo4j 4+. You can select the database you want to use programmatically via neo4j driver. I am not sure how neomodel handles that.

Comment: Yes, This was answered for the older version of the Neo4j. You can check if the Neomodel has a new version